# Increasing/ decreasing functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives, graphing-functions

We are given a random variable x with a pdf f(x) and F(x) is its distribution function. Let $$r(x) = \frac {xf(x)} {1-F(x)} $$

Then for $x< e^{\mu} $ and $$f(x) = \frac {e^ {1/2(\log x - \mu)^2}} {x (2 \pi)^{1/2}}$$

Is the function r(x) increasing, decreasing or constant in x?

I can't understand how to solve this- am I supposed to derive the F(x) function- replace it in the r(x) function and differentiate to find out? Because I tried that and got lost in the middle. Also wasn't sure if that was the right way to approach this question.

Comment: What is $pie$ in the denominator?

Comment: Pie value, 22/7

Comment: A pie is a type of cake, $\pi$ is a mathematical constant.

Comment: Oh thanks! edited the question.

Comment: @ClementC. I know places where you would be tried for heresy for that kind of statement. Pie is *decidedly not* cake.

Comment: I agree, but anyway neither of the two is an irrational constant. I think.

Comment: Deserts aside, What is the support of $F$? I'm assuming $x>0$?

Comment: It isn't really specified in the question. The only constraint for x is that it is less that $e^\mu$ and that it is a random variable

Comment: You have a $\log x$ in your definition of $f$, this is what makes me feel that $x>0$

Comment: Oh yeah that's true

Comment: the f(x) reminds me of a lognormal distribution, for some reason. Not sure if that's supposed to be relevant in the question